# Unable to Create Azure Resource Manager Project

Tags: cloud, azure, visual-studio-2015

I have just installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3 along with Azure SDK for Visual Studio 2015 and Azure PowerShell Tools.

When I try to create a new project under  Visual C#|Windows|Cloud|Azure Resource Group I get the following error after selecting a template and during the project creation.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I have re-installed Visual Studio and the Azure SDK but the problem persists.  I have also tried a number of devenv.exe command line options to clear cache and reset templates but nothing works.

Comment: [This thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4556b08e-103a-4c99-9f97-bba243e6987f/azure-ad-sync-version-1004940501-failing-with-failed-getting-registry-value?forum=WindowsAzureAD) has solutions for the case of missing permissions, if it applies to your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did.

Go to the control panel and uninstall all Visual Studio components and sub-components.  Then remove all old SDK's.  Then reinstall everything.

Comment: Yep I had to do the same.